# How can I get Windows Server 2008 to play sound?

Tags: audio, windows-server-2008

I am currently using Windows Server 2008 RC1 on my workstation (not by choice). Installation went very smoothly, but I can't get sound working. I started Windows Audio Service and installed only available Vista x64 drivers from Intel's site.

The problem is particularly strange because there aren't any warnings in device manager. My speakers/headphones are recognized when I plug them in. Also, there is no audio level detection in the audio mixer's audio level bar; no matter what I play, I can't see the green bar going up. I don't have any knowledge about Windows audio layers, so I can't see where the problem occurred.

The motherboard is D975XBX2 (i975X chipset).

EDIT:
I just noticed that audio is detected in the Control Panel > Sound panel. The bar goes green for the my default device (headphones) just as it should, but still shows nothing for the mixer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your newly installed audio device as the 'Default' audio device for windows? Most software uses the windows audio mapper to play sound. If this has no default device, you'll hear no sound.

Go to `Control Panel` > `Sounds and devices` > `Audio tab` and choose your default device for recording and playback.

Comment: Thanks for the answare, but my headphones are already the default device. I update my question with new info...

Comment: Did you plug the headphones in the front or rear panel? Sometimes the front and rear panels are separate audio devices.

Comment: I tried both. The strange thing is that usually the audio level bar is shown (and updated) even if there aren't any speakers/headphones (i.e. on my windows 7 machine). So I think the problem is in some lower level of audio processing.

Comment: That audio levels are always shown, wether or not your headphones or speakers are plugged in. What kind of audio device is it?

Answer (score 0):

RDP is a multi-channel protocol that allows a user to connect to a networked computer. Audio Redirection is a feature of RDP, which allows users to run an audio program on the remote desktop and have the sound redirected to their local computer.

Remote Desktop Connection Settings

Start Remote Desktop Connection
Click to expand Options
Select Local Resources tab.
Under Remote computer sound, ensure that Bring to this computer is selected.
Login to the server which needs audio enabled.
Now, you should hear the Windows startup login sound.
Finally, make sure Audio is configured correctly for all Windows applications over RDP:

Go to the sound control panel (Start-> (Settings->) Control Panel-> Sounds and Audio Devices)
Select Audio tab.
Select Microsoft RDP Audio Driver for the default playback device, if not already specified.
Check the "Use only default devices" checkbox at the bottom of the dialog.
Click the Voice tab.
Select Microsoft RDP Audio Driver for the default playback device, if not already specified.
Save settings by clicking on OK button.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is **not** using RDP.